# how to get VisualSVN Repository URL in C# using WMI

Tags: c#, svn, wmi, visualsvn-server

I want get the VisualSVN Repository URL from C# code. I know their is a way to get it by using WMI methods. But i didn't know how to do it. Can anyone help me..

Comment: @GrantWinney I'm leaning more towards this being a duplicate because the question is tagged `visualsvn-server`